# Can I get all options using the option group id?

Tags: plugin-development

I would like to return all the option that I registered under a specific group id.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean `group id`?

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. I found this Q&A with a search and it's completely clear to me, and should be to anyone who works with the Settings API. Edited question. The provided answer should be accepted as it does accurately answers the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a function. But you can create your own like this

```
function function_name(){

    global $new_whitelist_options;
    
    // array of option names
    $option_names = $new_whitelist_options[ 'your_option_group_name' ];

    // your_option_group_name is in register_setting( 'your_option_group_name', $option_name, $sanitize_callback ); 
    foreach ($option_names as $option_name) {
        echo get_option($option_name).'<br>';
    }
    

}
```

See: [here](https://themehybrid.com/board/topics/how-to-get-all-option-name-in-option-group)

**EDIT:**

**$new_whitelist_options** was renamed to **$new_allowed_options** since 5.5.0.

view change log [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/#changelog)

Comment: and if the global is not set? every time you need to use a global you are not initializing yourself, or 100% sure when and how it was initialized, you are most likely doing something wrong. If settings are registered only on admin side, this might generate errors on the front end

Comment: @MarkKaplun you are right this doesn't work for front end.

Comment: That's ok, I only need it to work on the backend

Comment: I think this is a good answer to the question and it should be flagged as Accepted. I've been looking for this info myself and it's very difficult to find.

In the WP [core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/option.php#L2024), the register_settings() function has this line:     `$new_whitelist_options[ $option_group ][] = $option_name;` In agreement with others, the provided Answer could have included a check for the existence and non-null value of $new_whitelist_options but that's PHP housekeeping that seems outside the scope of this Q&A.

Comment: From docs: "@since 5.5.0 $new_whitelist_options was renamed to new_allowed_options. Please consider writing more inclusive code."